# change "Products with label "Sale" to "quality" in magento

Tags: magento-1.8

In home page, under "specials" , you can see Products with label =" sale, best"

I want to change "Sale" to "Quality".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need modify the sprite with icons: http://boards.newtrendzonline.com/skin/frontend/default/galagiftshop/images/icons.png

Or you need create a new css rule with name "quatility" and create the image for this css rule.

In the file app/design/[package]/galagiftshop/catalog/product/list.phtml You have a differents conditions to show the icon.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. What is sprite? How i can insert another image in icons.png. Where i have to upload the "quality" image in the files? Please help me to find some solution.

Comment: Is it  possible to just Put the "quality" image instead of "New" and change the link. Is there any possibility. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, You need modify the image icons.png with photoshop or similar..., Put "quality" instead of "New". Upload and Replace the image to the following path: [magento_base_install]/skin/frontend/default/galagiftshop/images/icons.png And now you will see the results.

PS: If you don't know it the sprite css images: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Comment: Thanks for reply. Why those all images are in single image file "icons.jpg". Can you please help me in create a new css rule with name "quatility" and create the image for this css rule.

Comment: you read the link in my comment?? :S 

This forum is not for that purpose. Please if you have more questions about Magento I will be happy to help you.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your help. please help me for your second answer to create a new css rule with name "quatility" and create the image for this css rule. because I think It's very difficult to edit the icons. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user3483987 This comment is a new question which should be asked in a different forum which covers CSS.